# Weird Behavior of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a `Fragment` which has a `RecyclerView` in it.

On top of the `RecyclerView`, I place a `View`.

But to my surprise. `RecyclerView` is still swipable, isn't it suppose to be blocked by the `View`. How is it possible that it still receives touch events?

Any thoughts on this please? How can I prevent `RecyclerView` from receiving touch events when a `View` is on top of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have `View` On `RecyclerView` and you want to prevent touch on `RecyclerView`, you need to add TouchListener on `View`. Adding TouchListener on `View` will prevent touch on `RecyclerView`.

```html
((View)findViewById(R.id.view)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "view clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

If there is no touch event binded with the topmost view then it goes to the next layout.